# Apple Script containing javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, applescript

When I try to get element by ID or class or name in javascript, I get the value, but when I put the javascript in AppleScript, it doesn't return any value

```
tell application "Safari"
set title to do JavaScript "document.title;" in document 1 --this works
set ticketnumber to do JavaScript "document.getElementById(\"sys_readonly.sc_task.number\").value" as text in document 1
```

I have tried using single quotes instead of backslash, no difference
Here is a snip of the HTML code.

[image: HTML containing the ID that I reference in my code]

I have tried this in Chrome too and I get "missing value".

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
execute current application javascript "document.getElementById('sys_readonly.sc_task.number').value;"
    end tell
```

Comment: Based on your snippet, your code works for me in safari (with either double or single quotes). The `as text` is redundant and should be removed. FWIW, it would be more helpful if your html code was text rather than an image.